# Получить значения из form jinja2 aiohttp

Tags: python, flask, асинхронность, jinja2, aiohttp

У меня есть такая форма в index.html.

```
<form action="/{{chatname}}" method="post">
    <p><input type=text name=username> Имя пользователя
    <p><input type=text name=message_text> Текст сообщения

    <p><input type=button value=post>
</form>
```

И такой код метода обработчика

```
def handler_post_message(request):          
    chatname = request.match_info.get('chatname')
    # user = request.match_info.get('username')
    text = "Hello, " + chatname
    s = await loop.create_task(Chat.save_message(chatname, username, message_text))
    print(s)

    return aiohttp_jinja2.render_template('index.html', request, {'name': chatname, 'messages': Chat.messages})
```

Я хочу получить username и message_text в этой функции обработчике из формы jinja.
Во flask это можно сделать прописав request.form['username']. Но я не могу найти похожего работающего решения для aiohttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Даже не знаю, как вы искали. [Соответствующий раздел документации](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#http-forms).

```
data = await request.post()
login = data['username']
password = data['message_text']
```

Кстати, значения атрибутов в HTML должны быть обрамлены кавычками.